# GCD: shortest job termination with dispatch_apply

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch

Want to clarify some nuance regarding *dispatch_apply()* function. Let's suppose there are 100 blocks which I want to execute using *dispatch_apply()*. There are 2 cases:

1. Each block calls *[NSThread sleepForInterval:X]* method where X is unique number in range [1..100];
2. Each block executes some heavy mathematical computation, while the shortest takes 1 second, and the heaviest 100 seconds.

There are 8 active processors in the computer.
The jobs are deployed using *dispatch_apply(100, global_concurrent_queue);*

**Therefore the question: is it guaranteed that in both cases the shortest task will terminate first?**

**Update**: this is my goal - I want to build kind of threadpool that can accept unlimited number of tasks, run them concurrently and accept result only from first completed task. And I want to consider 2 different scenarios - when tasks allowed to sleep and when they are not.

Comment: Shortest answer: NO

Comment: Ok. Now to the second question: is there some SDK-level mean to guarantee that property?

Comment: The first guarantee of Grand Central Dispatch is that there are no guarantees, unless specifically stated. :)

Comment: Why, oh why, would you call `sleepForInterval:`?

Comment: You need to state what your goal is. Do you need one block to finished before another starts? Do you need all of the blocks to finish before something else begins? Do you need one block to collect the results of another block? There are literally dozens of thread coordination and synchronization tools, but you need to explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to build kind of threadpool that can accept unlimited number of tasks, run them concurrently and accept result only from first completed task. And I want to consider 2 different scenarios - when tasks allowed to sleep and when  they are not.